# Squash commits with commits from merged branch in between

Tags: git, squash

Have situation like this on branch BRANCH_SOMETHING:

```
FFF - 6th commit
EEE - 5th commit
DDD - 4th commit
Y commit from master
X commit from master
CCC - 3rd commit
BBB - 2nd commit
AAA - 1st commit
```

How to squash only my commits?

Comment: Didn't try that. Could you please write something more about it?

Comment: You can't squash your commits into one commit (as they stand). DDD needs X and Y. The best you can do is squash the first three and the last three or reorder your commits onto a different branch.

Answer (score 2):

The command you have to run is `git rebase -i AAA~` (note the `~`)
It will open your default text editor with the following rebase programm :

```bash
pick AAA 1st commit
pick BBB 2nd commit
pick CCC 3rd commit
pick X commit from master
pick Y commit from master
pick DDD 4th commit
pick EEE 5th commit
pick FFF 6th commit
```

You must edit the text to look like that :

```bash
pick X commit from master
pick Y commit from master
pick AAA 1st commit
squash BBB 2nd commit
squash CCC 3rd commit
squash DDD 4th commit
squash EEE 5th commit
squash FFF 6th commit
```

Save and exit the text editor.

Git will run and then open the text editor again giving you the opportunity to edit the commit message :

```bash
# This is a combination of 6 commits.
# This is the 1st commit message:

1st commit 

# This is the commit message #2:

2nd commit

...
```

Edit the commit message, save and exit.

Finally the history will look like that :

```bash
GGG squashed commit
Y commit from master
X commit from master
```

Note that you can also place commit X and Y after the squashed commit, jut edit the rebase programm accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the message! Nevertheless, I would also need to know how to change history. When I have commits one after another that I need to squash then I know how to do it. So please also tell me how to change the history. How to move commits up and down? Or how to copy/paste them to have correct flow? Tried normal copying but it's not working.

Comment: To move commits up and down, you really just have to move lines up or down in the rebase program. You just have to realize that the order in the rebase program is the chronological order and the order in history (`git log`) is the opposite. Do you have trouble moving lines up or down in your text editor? Perhaps `vi` opens and you don't know the shortcuts? Maybe the output of `git config core.editor` could help us in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do. (Taking into consideration that you do not want to squash the master commits into yours)

- Two commits

One commit will [squash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) 1,2,3 commits, the other one will squash
    4,5,6.

- Apply some branch magic

You can

1. Undo the rebase or merge (see [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) ) which led to the current structure of your branch (commits from master interleaved between yours).
2. Squash all your commits together.
3. Do a rebase or merge again with the master.

If the current branch structure is already there on the remote then you will have to force push after doing the changes in any of the above mentioned ways.